# How to make my list in ascending order in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist, adapter

I want to make my list in ascending order how can i do pragmatically. I tryed but not success.

```
CODE:

PhonebookAdapter adapter; // My Phonebook Adapter Class
final List<Phonebook> listOfPhonebook = new ArrayList<Phonebook>();
...
...
adapter = new PhonebookAdapter(this, listOfPhonebook);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Collections.sort(list);` You may need to `import java.util.Collections;`

For using custom properties for sorting you will have to implement `Comparator` Example:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Phonebook> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Phonebook p1, Phonebook p2) {
      return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
   }
}
```

And for sorting you will have to:

`Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());`

Comment: I used... Collections.sort(listOfPhonebook); but red mark shown for sort. And shown message : Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Phonebook>). The inferred type Phonebook is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T 
 extends Comparable<? super T>>

Comment: Please refer to the changes made.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Collections.sort(listOfPhonebook , new Comparator<Phonebook>() {
            public int compare(Phonebook phn1, Phonebook phn2) {
                return phn1.name.compareTo(phn2.name);
            }
        });
```

try this , assume name is variable of phonebook class and sorting as per name.